# Can a project made in Unreal Engine be converted to Unity project with a tool?

Tags: unity, unreal-4

Recently working on Unreal Engine for a project but want to convert the whole project to Unity. Is there any way?

Comment: No. Char limit.

Answer (score 10):

No.

There's no tool or automatic conversion process for this. You will need to make such a conversion almost entirely manually.

It's possible you will be able to find tools to bulk-convert any assets that are in one format to another, although there is a good chance Unity also supports whatever (source) asset format you're using in Unreal. Unity will not process `.uasset` files directly; you will need the source `.fbx` files, et cetera.

But all the code, anything in Blueprints or C++, will need to be rewritten in C# and `MonoBehavior` and likely heavily adapted in the process to Unity's rather different mode of operation.